# Does QGIS handle AREA_OR_POINT metadata tag?

Tags: qgis, gdal, sentinel-2

I used to think that Sentinel-2 L1C images stored on AWS are AREA_OR_POINT=Point, i.e. the origin lies in the centre of the pixel. Please, correct me if I'm wrong. For convenience I convert jpeg2000 to geotiff with gdal_translate, but it sets AREA_OR_POINT=Area by default. So I change the tag with gdal_edit. When I open the images as different layers the origin of the second image is not shifted by a half of the pixel size. Does QGIS handle AREA_OR_POINT tag?
Here are the steps to reproduce:

```
    # download an image
    wget --quiet http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/15/S/TD/2016/8/20/0/B03.jp2
    # convert to geotiff
    gdal_translate -of GTiff B03.jp2 B03.tif
    # make a copy
    cp B03.tif B03_point.tif
    # change the tag
    gdal_edit.py -mo AREA_OR_POINT=Point B03_point.tif
    # now open B03.tif and B03_point.tif in QGIS, the images are displayed as identical
```

I'm using QGIS 2.18.12 compiled against GDAL 2.1.0

Comment: Read http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc33_gtiff_pixelispoint with care and consider how QGIS should behave. I can't say.